# Accessing webservice from javascript in Phonegap Android

Tags: cordova

Anyone please suggest me some tutorial or share some useful to invoke webservice from javascript in Phonegap Android

Comment: you need to just ajax call  using javascript

Comment: i have tried that.but resulting in error.And i am new to Ajax too.Please share me the code or suggest me some good tutorial

Comment: what kind of web web service you can use, Php or java

Comment: ok first you need to allow access origin on config.xml    <access origin="*" />

Comment: I have tried that..errors persist stil.please suggest me some tutorial or share some code

Comment: threre is cross-domain problem so you need to set header on java web service setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", *);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {          
        var items = parseXml(xml);
        doStuff(items);
    }
});
});

function parseXml(xml) {

var items = [];
$(xml).find("category").each(function() {
    items.push({
        name: $(this).find("name").text(), 
        value: $(this).find("value").text()
    });
});
return items;
}


function doStuff(items) 
{

//Do some javascript stuff with the response
alert(items[0].name);
alert(tiems[0].value);
}
```

Comment: my datatype format is xml.can you please tell me what has to be the contentype and datatype for that.